# Error, status 200 load Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apache-cordova

Tenho uma chamada `ajax` que cai no `callback` de error e me trás um `status 200` e `statusText load`.

Segue o ajax:

```
$.ajax({


          type: "GET",
          crossDomain: "true",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          contentType: "text/xml", 
          url: "http://macchips.macpontoweb.com.br/WSVisita/Services/Comum/Autenticacao/AutenticacaoSrv.svc?Login",
          data: 'usuario='+usuario.value+'&senha='+senha.value,

          success: function(resposta){ 

           window.location.href="login.html";        

          alert(resposta);   

          },

          error: function(error){
            var falha = JSON.stringify(error);

            alert("Erro " + falha);
          }

        });
```

Estou tentando acessar um método de um webservice de outro dominio via uma aplicação mobile, usando cordova

Comment: Pelo que lembro, requisições ajax só podem ser feitas de um domínio para ele mesmo, a não ser que aquele servidor esteja configurado para aceitar chamadas ajax de fontes "externas"; Posso estar enganado... Quem lhe forneceu esse webservice, não demonstrou como usar ele?

Comment: Por que vc definiu 'dataType' e 'contentType'? Isso não causa nenhum contratempo?

Comment: @Jhonnyjks ContentType é o que você enviar para o servidor, e datatype é o que servidor retorna. Você pode definir os dois em uma solicitação

Comment: Ops, eu tava confundindo com o ContentType da resposta, q é ignorado quando setamos o dataType...

Comment: Qual seria o valor do parâmetro "?Login". Outra coisa, tentou verificar qual seria os parâmetros corretos a ser passado, não os valores?

Comment: Prametro login está indo vázio, o dataType, quando trocado para "json" retorna status 0 e não 200. Acho que você precisa verificar direitinho os parametros que serão enviados para esse WS. Verifique se os CORS estão habilitados.

Comment: O parâmetro Login pede um usuario e uma senha. Os CORS estão habilitados. Se eu tiro o contentType ou o dataType, o código não funciona também

Comment: Caro @GabrielDonato mesmo que no body do json o status esteja 200, provavelmente o statuscode retornado pelo servidor e que esta header do response esta sendo outro que não 200.

Comment: @GabrielDonato Acho que erros de CORS, podem retornar 200 mesmo... Pra tirar a dúvida coloque complete: function(xhr, textStatus) { console.log(xhr.status); } no Ajax. O CORS pode exigir headers especiais enviadas no request, dê uma olhada se não é esse caso, mesmo em servidores configurados para domínio "*". O próprio browser pode impedir uma requisição para outro domínio por ajax se não tiver os headers... Geralmente deve-se passar o header "Origin" com seu domínio -> Origin: http://foo.com